# "Controller as" syntax for ng-view

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I was wondering how I use the `Controller as` syntax in combination with `ngRoute` since I cant do `ng-controller="Controller as ctrl"`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the `controller as` syntax when you specify your controller in the `$routeProvider` configuration.

e.g.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/somePath', {
        template: htmlTemplate,
        controller: 'myController as ctrl'
    });
```

Answer (score 40):

Or, you can specify a controller assigning like when you create a new directive using `controllerAs`.

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/products', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/products.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController',
            controllerAs: 'products'
        });
```

Comment: I think your approach is a lot cleaner

Comment: Exactly, when implementing, please prefer this solution